# crypt_r() example?

Tags: c

Could anyone here give me an example on how to use the function crypt_r()?

From man page, it is unclear that the returned char * string is pointing to a block of memory allocated (in the heap) inside the function itself, or is still pointing to a static memory, like crypt()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html) manual:

> The crypt_r function does the same thing as crypt, but **takes an extra
> parameter which includes space for its result** (among other things), so
> it can be reentrant. data->initialized must be cleared to zero before
> the first time crypt_r is called.

[Kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/crypt.3.html) gives more details:

> crypt_r() is a reentrant version of crypt().  The structure pointed to
> by data is used to store result data and bookkeeping information.
> Other than allocating it, the only thing that the caller should do
> with this structure is to set data->initialized to zero before the
> first call to crypt_r().

Both `crypt` and `crypt_r` return a pointer to the encrypted password. Naturally, if you use `crypt_r` that memory will be somewhere in the `crypt_data` you passed.

#### EDIT Example, as requested:

```
struct crypt_data data;
data.initialized = 0;

char *enc = crypt_r(key, salt, &data);
printf("EncryptedL %s\n", enc);
```

Comment: But the prototype of the function is "char *crypt_r(const char *key, const char *salt, struct crypt_data *data)". So, the encrypted password is in the returned char * pointer, or in its third parameter, data?

Comment: Could you give me a small example on how to call it? Thanks!

Comment: With recent versions of Linux on x86_64, `sizeof(crypt_data)` is 128kB which might be too big to allocate safely on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <crypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  struct crypt_data data[1] = {0};
  char *res;

  res = crypt_r("password", "QX", data);
  printf("return value from crypt_r was %s\n", res);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc version 4.6.2 on my system

```
gcc crypttest.c -lcrypt
```

the result is

```
return value from crypt_r was QXZx61KdaYegc
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of the `_r` versions of GNU functions is to make them reentrant (and threadsafe in this case); eliminating the internal static buffers the non-_r versions use and return pointers to.

The `char*` returned is pointing into the data structure you allocated and passed in.